# if statement not following condition

Tags: python

my ifs are not selecting the correct data i have a lot of conditions so there must be a problem with my syntax probally

I tried changing the 'is' to '==' but no dice

```
 for CCode in CleanNumbers:
        CountryInitial = phonenumbers.region_code_for_number(CCode)            
            if CountryInitial is 'HK' or 'SG' or 'ID' or 'JP' \
                or 'MO' or 'MY' or 'KR' or 'TW':
                print(CountryInitial)
```

expect: HK SG ID etc(just the ones meeting the conditon)

result: every value i have in the array CleanNumbers

Comment: You may use `... in ...`

Comment: Use `if CountryInitial in ['HK', 'SG', 'ID', 'JP, ...]:` instead.

Comment: Also, the first capital letter usually indicates a class, in that case you should use `countryInitial` instead. Going even further, in python you will usually find `country_initial`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code basically checks if `'SG'` is non empty. Try this:

```
 for CCode in CleanNumbers:
        CountryInitial = phonenumbers.region_code_for_number(CCode)            
            if CountryInitial in ['HK', 'SG', 'ID', 'JP', 'MO', 'MY', 'KR', 'TW']:
                print(CountryInitial)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use `or` you need to write the complete condition again: `if CountryInitial is 'HK' or CountryInitial is 'SG' ...`

Using `or 'SG' or 'TH'` and etc will verify if the strings are empty or not.

The shorter version was already suggested, but for completeness, use a list instead: `if CountryInitial in ['HK', 'SG, ...]`

Answer (score 0):

Never mind i figured it out it should look like this

```
for CCode in CleanNumbers:
        CountryInitial = phonenumbers.region_code_for_number(CCode)            
            if CountryInitial is 'HK' or CountryInitial is 'SG' or CountryInitial is               'ID' or CountryInitial is 'JP' \
                or 'MO' or 'MY' or 'KR' or 'TW':
                print(CountryInitial)
```

Comment: but is there some shorter way?

Comment: This is still wront, `or 'MO'  or 'MY' or 'KR' or 'TW'` will always be true. Because you are checking if these values are empty or not. Use a list to simplify your code and impove readability